# How does an external non-conservative force act on a variable in the Hamiltonian formalism?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, torque

Consider a system subjected to an external non-conservative torque. The complete Hamiltonian is

$$
\mathcal{H}(q,p) = \mathcal{H}_{nat}(q,p) - \tau_{ext}(p) q \tag{1}
$$

where $\mathcal{H}_{nat}(q,p)$ is the unperturbed hamiltonian, $\tau_{ext}$ is the torque acting on the system and ($q$,$p$) are the system's coordinate and conjugated momentum.The torque on variables $q$ and $p$ are denoted as $T_q$ and $T_p$.

Hamilton's equation of motion are defined as $$\dot{q}=\partial\mathcal{H}_{nat}/\partial p + T_q\quad\text{and}\quad \dot{p}=- \partial\mathcal{H}_{nat}/\partial q + T_p.\tag{2}$$

Are the following definitions of $T_q$ and $T_p$ correct?

$$
T_q = - \frac{\partial\tau_{ext}}{\partial p} q \quad , \quad T_p = \tau_{ext}.\tag{3}
$$

Comment: To fix conventions, are you following a reference? Which page? Eq. (2) is not Hamilton's equations in a strict sense.

Comment: No particular reference. The system has an unperturbed hamiltonian and the torque acting on the system depends only on the momentum p. I need to define how the torque acts on p and q.

Comment: In Eq. (2) I just wanted to explicitly divide the action of the torque from the natural hamiltonian. Would you formalize this differently?

Comment: Yes, external sources should be introduced in the Hamiltonian itself; not in Hamilton's equations. If this is not possible, it is not a Hamiltonian formulation.

Comment: So in Eq.2, I should write the derivative of the complete hamiltonian and without T_q and T_p. Is that right?